# Redirect/ Routing issues in React and Express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, search

I am creating a flight search app that makes external api calls. The data will be reorganized and returned in search results component.

On submit, the data is sent to express and takes about 10 seconds or more to complete all the api calls.

I think I need a loader at some point for during the delay of api calls, but also I am unsure of how to send/render the data.

As it stands, I have two pages home.js- '/' where i make the search and is sent to the server side, and prices.js- '/search' which when loaded fetches the data from the json file. but i do not have them connected

Both files work but I need to connect them. When I press submit, the user inputs are sent to server and the api calls are made but in order to see the results i have to manually refresh localhost:3000/search.

In express app after all the api calls, I tried res.redirect method, however the error given was setting the headers after sent to the client.

In react, I tried after submitting, to redirect to the search page. However I could not get it to redirect and also as soon as the /search page is called, it fetches the data from the file. This will happen before the api has finished writing to file and therefore the previous search results will render.

```
--in app.js 
setTimeout(() => {
        Promise.all([promise, promise2]).then(values => {

            return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/search');

        });
    }, 25000);

I had to wrap the api calls in promises so it will only redirect after all is written to file.
```

(in react prices.js)

```
 componentDidMount() {

   fetch('/search')
            .then(res => {

                return res.json()

            })
            .then(res => {

                console.log(res.toString());


                this.setState({flightData: res});

            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
```

home.js

````
home.js

```
onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
       originOne: e.target.value, originTwo: e.target.value});
    };


 onSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();

     const { originOne, originTwo ,redirectToResult} = this.state;


};


```
app.js - I have all the functions calling each other in a waterfall style ( probably not the best way I know) 

app.post('/', function getOrigins(req,res) {

     var OrigOne;
     var OrigTwo;

....

function IataCodeSearchOrg1(res, OrigOne, OrigTwo) {
... 
findPrices(res,A,B)
}

 function findPrices(res, A, B) {

         promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
...
}
}

All the methods are called within eachother. The api calls are in a loop and after each iteration they are written to the json file. 

All these functions are in the app.post method and i tried to res.redirect but it did not work.
````

Comment: Can you share the rest of the relevant server code? The portion from app.js seems incomplete

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You can't redirect server-side from an XHR request. You would need to redirect client-side.

e.g.

```
componentDidMount() {

   fetch('/search')
       .then(res => res.json())
       ...
       .then(() => window.location = '/myredirecturl')
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have the data rendering on the prices page ok, but I am unable to redirect to the prices page once the api calls are done in express. Although i might not be doing this the right way, should i be redirecting to the prices page server side or client side?